# How to display label information for a selected autodesk viewer node?

Tags: c#, jquery, autodesk-forge

I want to display a label with detailed information for a selected component from auto desk viewer.
Any client side coding available?

Comment: `I want to display a label with detailed information for a selected component`, please show us what you have tried so far and what is not working so we can better help you. As of right now, the question is asking for recommendations and or offsite material in which is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me the simplest way to achieve this is to show the built-in property panel upon clicking an component:

```
viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
     viewer.getPropertyPanel(true).setVisible(true)
})
```

If you'd like to customize a bit then you can retrieve the properties for a given `dbid` (which identifies a component) and display them in a panel (see how to create custom panels [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/extension-skeleton-toolbar-docking-panel)):

```
let dbIdArray = viewer.getSelection(); // obtain ids of selected nodes
model.getBulkProperties(dbIdArray, null, props=>{
   // do stuff with properties here
}) // retrieve properties for an array of nodes

//alternatively retrieve properties for a single node
viewer.getProperties(dbId, props=>{
  // do stuff with properties here
})
```

See doc for `getBulkProperties` [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) and relevant samples [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/0c0db2d6426f4ff4aea1042813ed10da17c63554/src/components/Viewer.Toolkit/Viewer.Toolkit.js) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-properties-viewer-net-lambda-dynamodb)

And remember to add reactivity to user selection you can subscribe to the `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` event.

Comment: I am getting this error while using the below code viewer.getPropertyPanel().setVisible(true)... Error: Cannot read property 'setVisible' of undefined

Comment: That's because the property panel has never been opened/initialized - use `viewer.getPropertyPanel(true)`